# Lexus IS 2007, wont start, electrical issues noticed.

Tags: lexus, cranks-wont-run

As of about a week ago the head lights started acting funny, some would turn on some wont, all of a sudden they would turn on. then it became an issue with them on top of that turning off by themselves. id have to turn them off and on and they would come on. sometimes they'd stay stuck on high beam other times they would work normally, and not always all on. Then today i went t the super market, about 1miles from home, after leaving the super market and turning the car on the steering wheel was really really REALLY hard, all lights on dash board indicating all problems were all on, nav/radio off and unable to it back turn on. Since it was late i drove straight home and parked the car in my driveway. A few hours later after doing a little research on this very helpful site i decided to go down and check on the fuse box. Before doing so however I opened the car and attempted* to turn it on.
~ The car wont start, head lights come on, the dash board seems to think is on because when i got out it beeped and displayed the key is not near message. it just clicks and makes a few weird noises but the engine doesnt turn.. Please help!! I should mention live in Dominican Republic, so a dealership is not an option and going to a mechanic not knowing myself whats wrong is like asking for them to take my money and possibly make things worst. i purchased this car about 2 months ago and everything was fine until last week. please help!!

Comment: Have you checked if the battery is flat?  You would get all sorts of strange things happen if this was the case.  There may be enough power for your lights to work, but the voltage could be too low to power the electronics or run the starter.  Why the battery is flat is another problem, maybe your alternator has failed.

Answer (score 1):

It is a long shot, but I think all these problems could be a charging issue.  You first need to check if your battery is now flat, that could cause all you latest problems.  After charging/replacing the battery if necessary, you then need to check if the alternator is running over/under voltage and rectify that.  You may need a new alternator.  A simple voltmeter should be able to diagnose this.